# How do I see if a file is readable by a specific user on Linux?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have a complicated file hierarchy and I don't want to check the permissions on each directory. Is there any way to find out immediately if one file is readable by a given user? (outside of logging in as that user)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will only work if you have root privileges

---

**if the user has a valid login shell**

`su username -c 'ls /long/dir/user/filename'`

**if the user has a nologin shell** `/sbin/nologin` and similar:

`su username -s /bin/sh -c 'ls /long/dir/user/filename'`

**To find out why** a user cannot access a file (builds readable output tree with permissions):

```
# namei -om /home/someuserhomedir/Maildir/

f: /home/someuserhomedir/Maildir/
dr-xr-xr-x root     root      /
drwxr-xr-x root     root      home
drwx------ someuser somegroup someuserhomedir
drwx------ someuser somegroup Maildir
```

Comment: That says Permission denied on everything, even '/'.

Comment: right, I was gonna suggest the ticks, it works now. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to figure out why you can't access a file use `namei`: `sudo -u user namei -m /long/dir/user/filename`

Comment: @fuero That's a good one, didn't know namei, thanks!